# Tracking app installs with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: ios, react-native-fbsdk

I have a iOS React-Native app that uses the react-native-fbsdk.

I'm doing some ad campaigns on Facebook to promote the app.

In Facebook for Developers I already linked the correct advertisement and company IDs to my Facebook-app.

Now I want to know, which installations came from what campaign, but it seems that the react-native-fbsdk doesn't send this event.

My hope was this would be done automatically.

Anyway, I found this list of [standard events](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.m), but install isn't part of it.

Comment: Hi K, were you able to find the solution? The docs say App install is part of Automatically Logged Events but I am unable to see proper App Installs in my FB console.

Comment: I think it works automatically in newer versions now.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I never looked into it again. I think, it will just be tracked automatically by the FBSDK, but can't say for sure, sorry.